# Jquery change the value of dropdown from a dropdown change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the value of two dropdown lists when a third one changes, to that dropdown's new value:

```
<script>
$('select[name="d1"]').change(function() {
  $('select[name="d2"]').val(this.value);
  $('select[name="d3"]').val(this.value);
});
</script>
```

Nothing happens.

Comment: You probably need to put script in document.ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for starters, work your way when you get this to work :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select[name="d1"]').change(function() {
      $('select[name="d2"]').val(this.value);
      $('select[name="d3"]').val(this.value);
   });
});
```

Comment: Honest mistake my friend, been forgetting this a couple lot of times now. XD

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(function() {

    $('select[name="d1"]').change(function() {
        $('select[name="d2"]').val($(this).val());
        $('select[name="d2"]').html($(this).val());
    });

});
```